# Can I Query a Pdf Reader If It's On The Last Page?

Tags: linux, pdf, shell-script, bash-scripting, pdf-reader

I'm writing a wrapper shell-script to do the following:

1. Searches a directory for .pdf/.djv files.
2. makes an ordered "playlist" of files
3. Opens 1st file in a pdf reader.
4. Automatically change to the next page every 0.5/1.0/2.0s (user configurable)
5. When a .pdf/.djvu reaches its end, the next pdf is loaded from the "playlist" and so on till the "playlist" gets exhausted.

Assuming that I don't have access to the source-code of the Pdf Reader, how would the script know it's come to the end of the .pdf?

Comment: Which PDF reader are you using? If you use a PDF reader with a DBUS interface and exposes the page numbers via DBUS you could query that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25486470/1030675

Comment: I'll using any program that can render scanned images (wiyhin .pdf/.djvu) fast enough. After looking at your reply, I searched to find out what DBUS is and found that all the 'options' I had in my head were DBUS compatible (from Evince to Okular and a lot in betweens).